# How to get the inner nodes data values in firebase dynamically without changing the URL

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iteration

I want to iterate through the Json structure and get the data from the top node to the inneremost node iteratively

I have tried this [Child_added](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/firebase/firebase_event_types.htm) but it does not work This is the Json structure:

```
{
  "0153" : {
    "0163" : {
      "Email" : "vikram@dept.com"
              },
    "Email" : "joel@dept.com"
             }
}
```

this is my code:

```
var dbref=new Firebase("https://logintrialapp.firebaseio.com/Employee/OrgHierachy/0153");
var login=localStorage.getItem("Email");  
var i=0;
var j=0;
dbref
   .once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
       j=j+1;                   
       console.log("value is:",j);
       console.log(snapshot.val());
       snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
           i=i+1;                                                                           
           var newPlayer = childsnapshot.val();
           console.log("email: " + newPlayer.Email);         
           console.log("key:"+ childsnapshot.key);                                                                                                           
           console.log(i);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       });
   });
```

Here is the o/p:

```
value is: 1
Checkworks.html:40 Object {0163: Object, Email: "joel@dept.com"}0163: ObjectEmail: "joel@dept.com"__proto__: Object
Checkworks.html:55 email: vikram@dept.com
Checkworks.html:57 key:function (){D("Firebase.DataSnapshot.key",0,0,arguments.length);return this.Y.key()}
Checkworks.html:59 1
Checkworks.html:55 email: undefined
Checkworks.html:57 key:function (){D("Firebase.DataSnapshot.key",0,0,arguments.length);return this.Y.key()}
Checkworks.html:59 2
```

How can I get the data from the inner node while keeping the same url for the reference , what I mean is right now I have gone down(OrgHierachy/0153) to the inner node in the url to get the data , is it possible to get the data while keeping a reference to the topmost node in the URL.

Comment: Could you apply some consistent indentation, please? That's not an easy read.

Comment: also referred to following link it has all the locatoins hardcoded https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen can you have a look

Comment: Your data structure is inconsistent. You have an object `0163` with an `Email` *property* and then you have an *object* named `Email`. To allow systematic display of such data, it should follow a common data model

Comment: email is not an object, it is the the email property of object 0153

Comment: 0163 is nested within 0153, I need to read the email property but I am able to read only the top level node that is 0153 objects email